# How to make custom login only for admin in laravel?

Tags: mysql, laravel, authentication, eloquent

I use laravel ui for authentication. Now, I want to custom login where only the admin can log in, otherwise, the user will be redirected to the user's login page. In the user's table one column name **"is_admin"**. If is_admin == 1 then returns to admin panel otherwise return to user's login page.  Here is my custom login method

```
public function adminAuth(Request $request) {

    $request->validate([
        'email'    => 'required',
        'password' => 'required',
    ]);
    $credentials = $request->only('email', 'password');
      if (Auth::attempt($credentials)) {
        $user = User::where('email', $request->email)->first();
        if ($user->is_admin == 1) {
            return redirect()->route('admin.home');
        } else {
            return redirect()->back()->with('error', 'Oppes! You have no permission ');
        }
    }
    return redirect()->back()->with('error', 'Oppes! You have entered invalid credentials');
}
```

Problem has solved now

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you to add below logic to the `redirectTo()` method of authenticate middleware, then define other view and controller for admin login.

App\Http\Middleware\Authenticate

```php
protected function redirectTo($request)
{
    if (!$request->expectsJson() && Str::is('admin*', request()->path())) {

        return route('admin.login');
    }

    if (!$request->expectsJson()) {
        return route('login');
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use auth guards.

```
if (Auth::guard('admin')->attempt($credentials)) {
  //
}
```

You can define your guards in the config/auth.php file in your project.

Alternatively, you could add a condition to Auth::attempt(). as like below:

```
if (Auth::attempt(['email' => $email, 'password' => $password, 'is_admin' => 1])) {
// The user is admin
}
```

Learn more here: https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/authentication

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, I am not a Laravel dev but as soon as you confirm the credentials of the individual attempting to log in, you can do something like this:

1. Get the 'is_admin' value of the user
2. if is_admin == 1
3. direct user to admin page
4. else if is_admin != 1
5. ```
   direct user to user page.
   ```
6. end if

Comment: Problem has solved. I add this    if (Auth::attempt($credentials)) {
            $user = User::where('email', $request->email)->first();
            if ($user->is_admin == 1) {
                return redirect()->route('admin.home');
            } else {
                return redirect()->back()->with('error', 'Oppes! You have no permission to access this');
            }
        }